# edit .bashrc from shell script and source it

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script that takes care of all the setup for my aws servers, but I am caught in a catch-22 with my `.bashrc`. I need to source `.bashrc` from the script so the next commands can execute properly, but I cannot source `.bashrc` from my script. I have read other posts about this, but those solutions still require me to source from the parent shell and cannot be done within the script.

I tried

```
$ echo "alias sbrc='source ~/.bashrc'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

in my script, but I still need to source `.bashrc` outside my script before `sbrc` works and I still can't use `sbrc` in my shell script.

Here's the script thus far (tried with and without the echo command listed above, both fail):

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
nvm install 6.0
```

Comment: Why can't you source `.bashrc` from your script?

Comment: doesn't work. Like installing nvm then doing source ~/.bashrc and then doing nvm install 6.0 from the script you get command nvm not found. From an askUbuntu post "A shell script is run in its own shell instance...By contrast the source command doesn't start a new shell instance but uses the current shell so the changes remain." So I think using source ~/.bashrc in the script is working in the child script but not the parent?

Comment: That should work. Since you're running `nvm install 6.0` from the script, it should use its own environment, which was updated by `source .bashrc`. It doesn't matter that the caller's shell wasn't updated.

Comment: Note that aliases are not normally expanded inside scripts, maybe that's your problem.

Comment: I've also tried with cd and source .bashrc as well as source ~/.bashrc, but always get nvm command not found. will edit with full script.

Comment: Why would you need to source the ~/.bashrc ? You can simply define the alias that's it. Try to understand what `source .bashrc` is doing first. Once you got that, you'll realize that it is not necessary.

Comment: I need to install nvm, then run 'nvm install 6.0'. nvm adds to your .bashrc and then at the end of the install says: => Appending source string to /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm     So I need to source .bashrc to reload it and have the nvm command available.

Comment: If I'm understanding you @hek2mgl then you are saying that I can make an alias for nvm and just start using it? But the installer makes the alias, and even if I made my own, wouldn't I need to reload .bashrc (like source, . , or exec) to make that available?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to install nvm and activate it with a single command. That's doable by implementing the desired command as a shell function rather than a separate script.

Add this function to your `.bashrc`:

```
install_and_activate_nvm()
{
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash
    source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
install_and_activate_nvm
nvm install 6.0
```

Comment: i need it within a shell script because i want to bootstrap my server with one command and let it run (there is more to the script above), not go into the .bashrc on every server i spin up. i found the answer on unix / linux SE but it doesn't explain why sourcing .bashrc doesn't work. the solution was to put . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh in the script